# What's the most efficient way to normalize text from column into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

In T-SQL I have a column with some text in it with a format like the following:

```
[Key1:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]
[Key2:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]
[Key3:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]
```

where there can be any number of bracket sets, but usually between 3 and 6. I'm looking for a way to quickly format them into a temp table or table variable so I can report on the data. For example, I'd want the table format to be:

```
|Key|Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|Column 4|Column 5|  
|Key 1|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|  
|Key 2|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|  
|Key 3|Value 1|Value 2|Value 3|Value 4|Value 5|
```

I know this is pushing the limits of SQL and should be handled through modification of the application, but I'm hoping there's something clever I can do with T-SQL for now.

Comment: What are you using for your database?  SQLServer Oracle, other?  It will determine what options you have.

Comment: SQL Server - I believe 2014.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a maximum number of columns, a little XML within a CROSS APPLY.

If unknown, you would have to go DYNAMIC.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'[Key1:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]')
,(2,'[Key2:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]')
,(3,'[Key3:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(replace(replace(SomeCol,'[',''),']',''),':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Pos1    Pos2    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5    Pos6    Pos7    Pos8    Pos9
1   Key1    Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  NULL    NULL    NULL
2   Key2    Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  NULL    NULL    NULL
3   Key3    Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

> **EDIT**

I should add, the `ltrim(rtrim(...))` is optional and the `varchar(max)` is my demonstrative default.

> **EDIT - One String delimited with CRLF**

```
Declare @S varchar(max)='
[Key1:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]
[Key2:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]
[Key3:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]
'

Select B.*
 From  (
        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@S,char(13)+char(10),'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
       ) A
 Cross Apply (
               Select  Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(replace(replace(RetVal,'[',''),']',''),':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
       ) B
 Where A.RetVal is not null
```

Comment: This almost gives me what I need. The input is one long string so i still need to split each set of [] data into a set I can operate on here. I think this will get me there though - I'm going to tinker with it and report back.

Comment: @ShawnHubbard Easy fix,  I wasn't clear that that was one long string.  give me a moment

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to split a string when you know the maximum number of columns is to use the [Cascading CROSS APPLY](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/97545/) technique. Let's say you know that their will be no more than 10 items in your string. You could do this:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(1000) = '[Key1:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]'

SELECT 
  [key] = SUBSTRING(t.string,1,d1.d-1),
  col1  = SUBSTRING(t.string,d1.d+1,d2.d-d1.d-1),
  col2  = SUBSTRING(t.string,d2.d+1,d3.d-d2.d-1),
  col3  = SUBSTRING(t.string,d3.d+1,d4.d-d3.d-1),
  col4  = SUBSTRING(t.string,d4.d+1,d5.d-d4.d-1),
  col5  = SUBSTRING(t.string,d5.d+1,d6.d-d5.d-1),
  col6  = SUBSTRING(t.string,d6.d+1,d7.d-d5.d-1),
  col7  = SUBSTRING(t.string,d7.d+1,d8.d-d5.d-1),
  col8  = SUBSTRING(t.string,d8.d+1,d9.d-d5.d-1),
  col9  = SUBSTRING(t.string,d9.d+1,d10.d-d5.d-1)
FROM (VALUES (REPLACE(REPLACE(@string,']',':'),'[',''))) t(string)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX(':',t.string)))                   d1(d)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d1.d+1),0)))  d2(d)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d2.d+1),0)))  d3(d)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d3.d+1),0)))  d4(d)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d4.d+1),0)))  d5(d)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d5.d+1),0)))  d6(d)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d6.d+1),0)))  d7(d)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d7.d+1),0)))  d8(d)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d8.d+1),0)))  d9(d)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d9.d+1),0)))  d10(d);
```

To use this technique against a table with the strings stored in rows would be like this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (someid int identity, somestring varchar(1000));
INSERT @table(somestring) VALUES 
('[Key1:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]'),
('[Key2:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]'),
('[Key3:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5]'),
('[Key4:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5:Value6:Value7:Value8]'),
('[Key5:Value1:Value2:Value3:Value4:Value5:Value6:Value7:Value8:Value9:Value10]');

SELECT * 
FROM @table s
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT 
    [key]  = SUBSTRING(t.string,1,d1.d-1),
    dCount = LEN(t.string)-LEN(REPLACE(t.string,':','')),
    col1   = SUBSTRING(t.string,d1.d+1,d2.d-d1.d-1),
    col2   = SUBSTRING(t.string,d2.d+1,d3.d-d2.d-1),
    col3   = SUBSTRING(t.string,d3.d+1,d4.d-d3.d-1),
    col4   = SUBSTRING(t.string,d4.d+1,d5.d-d4.d-1),
    col5   = SUBSTRING(t.string,d5.d+1,d6.d-d5.d-1),
    col6   = SUBSTRING(t.string,d6.d+1,d7.d-d6.d-1),
    col7   = SUBSTRING(t.string,d7.d+1,d8.d-d7.d-1),
    col8   = SUBSTRING(t.string,d8.d+1,d9.d-d8.d-1),
    col9   = SUBSTRING(t.string,d9.d+1,d10.d-d9.d-1)
  FROM (VALUES (REPLACE(REPLACE(s.somestring,']',':'),'[',''))) t(string)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX(':',t.string)))                   d1(d)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d1.d+1),0)))  d2(d)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d2.d+1),0)))  d3(d)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d3.d+1),0)))  d4(d)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d4.d+1),0)))  d5(d)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d5.d+1),0)))  d6(d)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d6.d+1),0)))  d7(d)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d7.d+1),0)))  d8(d)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d8.d+1),0)))  d9(d)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':',t.string,d9.d+1),0)))  d10(d)
) split
WHERE LEN(s.somestring)-LEN(REPLACE(s.somestring,':','')) < 10
```

If you don't know the maximum number of possible items you could take this logic and wrap it in some Dynamic SQL that creates the correct number of CROSS APPLY's. I don't have time to put together that logic but, to get the maximum number of possible delimiters you could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @maxDelimiters tinyint = 
  (SELECT MAX(LEN(s.somestring)-LEN(REPLACE(s.somestring,':',''))) FROM @table s);
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to use John's technique, you could also use Dynamic SQL to create his query with the exact number of "pos" values required.

Comment: You've got me curious now.  I'll run some benchmarks in a bit and let you know.  +1

Comment: Working with a sample of 5,000 records, 5 runs each.  Mine had an average of 963ms (953 min 983 max).  Yours had an average of 7,635ms (7,566 min 7,773 max)

Comment: Thanks John... Are you running it with show execution plan on? For me that slows it to a crawl. The other problem could be the how I'm removing the brackets in the first apply, sometimes derived values slow things down a bit. I'm going to play around with this a little and post some updated code.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Please post the compare code and sample data somewhere and leave a link in the comments. I'm also curious now...

Comment: @ZoharPeled on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=efc0777883996a9e424b1b19a8c70682  slightly different than my machine, but still a dramatic diff   1.5 sec vs 5.7 sec

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Curiouser and curiouser. Run it at dbfiddle with SQL 2017 (Linux) selected. They run almost the same speed. :-S