# SQL STRING_SPLIT not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a string like so:

```
DECLARE @columnCamera varchar(MAX) = 'aaa,bbb,ccc'
```

and I am trying to split these and loop through, I am stuck on the splitting part:

```
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@columnCamera, ',')
```

But I get this error:

> Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.

What is the proper way to split a string and loop through it?

Comment: what version of sql are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: The `STRING_SPLIT` function only became available in SQL Server 2016, so I'm afraid you don't have that function available.

Comment: I get that, what is the proper way to split a string in SQL...I did some digging and it looks super hard

Comment: It's supposed to be hard. CSV data is anathema to good SQL practice.

Comment: Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50068426/5089204). It was closed as duplicate and it is a perfect duplicate to this itself (including the existing sub-optimal answer).

Comment: I voted to close this as it is a duplicate. One hint: I'd suggest to read the younger answers rahter than the highest rated. They were good at their times but are outdated....