# how to split comma separated string in sql server into n-number of columns

Tags: sql-server, string, split

1. I have a table **tb1** with one column **OppName** as : (8-values in
   a row with csv)

   ```
   ["OpportunityName","Fact","","","StartDate","EndDate","IsActive","UpdateDate"]
   ```

   I am trying to split each comma separated values into a separate
   column as :

   ```
         c1              c2      c3 c4 c5 c6 c7          c8
   "OpportunityName"   "Fact"    .........            "UpdateDate"
   ```

   What I did is :

   **Step 1:** removed [] from string as :

   ```
      UPDATE tb1 
      SET [OppName] = REPLACE(REPLACE([OppName], '[', ''), ']', '')

   # output: "OpportunityName","Fact","","","StartDate","EndDate","IsActive","UpdateDate"
   ```

   **Step 2:** split string in vars and inserting all vars into tb2 for each row:

   ```
   DECLARE @list varchar(8000)
   DECLARE @pos INT
   DECLARE @len INT
   DECLARE @value varchar(8000)
   DECLARE @x nvarchar(max)

   SET @list = '"OpportunityName","Fact","","","StartDate","EndDate","IsActive","UpdateDate",'

   set @pos = 0
   set @len = 0

   WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @list, @pos+1)>0
   BEGIN
       set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @list, @pos+1) - @pos
       set @value = SUBSTRING(@list, @pos, @len)
       set @value = REPLACE (@value, '"', '')       
       PRINT @value -- for debug porpose  
       set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @list, @pos+@len) +1
       --Append values to x
       set @x =  (@x  +','+ @value) 
   END

     PRINT @x
      --Inserting in tb2
     Insert into  tb2 values(@x)
   ```

   But string is not properly concatenating

   can someone help me here

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063415/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-normalize-text-from-column-into-a-table/50064225#50064225

Comment: Did you check, if there are any commas within your strings? e.g. "Fact, Fact2, Fact3"? This would break your splitting approach. Furthermore: How are you processing these records? Is it some ETL like via SSIS or something? In this case I would uggest using the C# Split function.

Answer (score 1):

SQL 2016 has function STRING_SPLIT. In combination with PIVOT you can do following:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT value, ColumnName = 'c' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR)
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('"OpportunityName","Fact","","","StartDate","EndDate","IsActive","UpdateDate"',',')
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
pivot (MAX(value) FOR ColumnName IN("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8")) AS p;
```

[image]