# String Split into column instead of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample data:

```
id  email_address                                   email_new
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   a.b@wellsfargoadvisors.com                      a.b@wellsfargoadvisors.com
2   c.b@RaymondJames.com; abc@RaymondJames.com      c.b@RaymondJames.com
2   c.b@RaymondJames.com; abc@RaymondJames.com      abc@RaymondJames.com
3   a.b@boa.com; bbc@boa.com; hh@bankofamerica.com  a.b@boa.com
3   a.b@boa.com; bbc@boa.com; hh@bankofamerica.com  bbc@boa.com
3   a.b@boa.com; bbc@boa.com; hh@bankofamerica.com  hh@bankofamerica.com
```

I used the following query to split a '`;` ' separated string into rows:

```
SELECT
    id, email_address, email_new
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         id, email_address, 
         Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)') AS email_new 
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              id, email_address, CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(email_address, '; ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) email_new
          FROM 
              table) AS A 
     CROSS APPLY 
         email_new.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) x
GROUP BY
    id, email_address, email_new
```

Problem with my query is that I don't want to create a new row for every split email address- I would like to add a new column for it.. Ideally, something along the lines of this:

```
id  email_1                      email_2                email_3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   a.b@wellsfargoadvisors.com   null                   null
2   c.b@RaymondJames.com         abc@RaymondJames.com   null
3   a.b@boa.com                  bbc@boa.com            h@bankofamerica.com
```

There are as many as 3 separated email addresses in email_address column. Any suggestions? In case it grows beyond 3- it is best if answer could account for n columns.

Comment: Is there always a semicolon? you can just use `substring()`, also split it with the ID and you can just pivot it back into columns

Comment: How many emails you will have possibly ?

Comment: @Random_User They are always separated the same way: semicolon and space `'; '`

Comment: @M.Ali how many separated emails in `email_address`? 3 maximum

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063415/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-normalize-text-from-column-into-a-table/50064225#50064225

Comment: Thank you @JohnCappelletti - didn't see that previous post before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
Declare @t table (Id INT, email_address VARCHAR(1000) , email_new VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1   ,'a.b@wellsfargoadvisors.com'                      , 'a.b@wellsfargoadvisors.com'),
(2   ,'c.b@RaymondJames.com; abc@RaymondJames.com'      , 'c.b@RaymondJames.com'      ),
(2   ,'c.b@RaymondJames.com; abc@RaymondJames.com'      , 'abc@RaymondJames.com'      ),
(3   ,'a.b@boa.com; bbc@boa.com; hh@bankofamerica.com'  , 'a.b@boa.com'               ),
(3   ,'a.b@boa.com; bbc@boa.com; hh@bankofamerica.com'  , 'bbc@boa.com'               ),
(3   ,'a.b@boa.com; bbc@boa.com; hh@bankofamerica.com'  , 'hh@bankofamerica.com'      );
```

**Query**

```
WITH Emails (ID , XmlEmail, email_new)
AS
(
    SELECT Id
          , CONVERT(XML,'<Emails><email>'  
                    + REPLACE(email_address,';', '</email><email>') 
                    + '</email></Emails>') AS XmlEmail
          , email_new
      FROM @t
)

 SELECT   ID
        , XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)') AS Email1
        , XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[2]','varchar(100)') AS Email2
        , XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[3]','varchar(100)') AS Email3
        , XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[4]','varchar(100)') AS Email4
        , XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[5]','varchar(100)') AS Email5
        , email_new
FROM Emails
```

**Result**

```
╔════╦════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║           Email1           ║        Email2         ║        Email3         ║ Email4  ║ Email5  ║         email_new          ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ a.b@wellsfargoadvisors.com ║ NULL                  ║ NULL                  ║ NULL    ║ NULL    ║ a.b@wellsfargoadvisors.com ║
║  2 ║ c.b@RaymondJames.com       ║  abc@RaymondJames.com ║ NULL                  ║ NULL    ║ NULL    ║ c.b@RaymondJames.com       ║
║  2 ║ c.b@RaymondJames.com       ║  abc@RaymondJames.com ║ NULL                  ║ NULL    ║ NULL    ║ abc@RaymondJames.com       ║
║  3 ║ a.b@boa.com                ║  bbc@boa.com          ║  hh@bankofamerica.com ║ NULL    ║ NULL    ║ a.b@boa.com                ║
║  3 ║ a.b@boa.com                ║  bbc@boa.com          ║  hh@bankofamerica.com ║ NULL    ║ NULL    ║ bbc@boa.com                ║
║  3 ║ a.b@boa.com                ║  bbc@boa.com          ║  hh@bankofamerica.com ║ NULL    ║ NULL    ║ hh@bankofamerica.com       ║
╚════╩════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: thank you! I adjusted ';' to '; ' and it worked perfectly. Any chance for me not to specify # of columns- for it to be created based on # of '; ' split entries?

Comment: @user8834780 for that you will need to look into Dynamic Pivot. That is a whole different beast on it own.

Comment: Sounds scary, and like a brand new question. I'll leave it at that. Thank you!