# Specify multiple characters for substring condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

As per answer in [String Split into column instead of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338013/string-split-into-column-instead-of-rows/50338190?noredirect=1#comment87693221_50338190), I noticed that sometimes `XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)') AS Email1` returns multiple emails that are separated either by a space (\s) or by a semi-colon (;). This is the way they were inputed- nothing wrong with query.

I was trying to only take value before that space, so this is what I came up with:

```
CASE CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)')), 1)
WHEN 0 THEN LTRIM(XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)'))
ELSE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)')), 1, CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)')), 1) - 1) end as Email_1
```

However, I can't do that because I also have cases with `';'`.

Any idea how can I implement both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead. With no data to test, I can't say this'll work, however, it'll probably be something like:

```
CASE PATINDEX('%[ ;]%', LTRIM(XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)')))
WHEN 0 THEN LTRIM(XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)'))
ELSE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)')), 1, PATINDEX('%[ ;]%',LTRIM(XmlEmail.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)'))) - 1) end as Email_1
```

OP says this doesn't work, however, it does seem to work for me:

```
DECLARE @Email varchar(500) = 'ab@nmfn.com ab@northwesternmutual.com';

SELECT
CASE PATINDEX('%[ ;]%', LTRIM(@Email))
WHEN 0 THEN LTRIM(@Email)
ELSE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(@Email), 1, PATINDEX('%[ ;]%',LTRIM(@Email)) - 1) end as Email_1;
```

Returns: `ab@nmfn.com`

```
DECLARE @Email varchar(500) = 'ab@nmfn.com;ab@northwesternmutual.com';

SELECT
CASE PATINDEX('%[ ;]%', LTRIM(@Email))
WHEN 0 THEN LTRIM(@Email)
ELSE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(@Email), 1, PATINDEX('%[ ;]%',LTRIM(@Email)) - 1) end as Email_1;
```

Also returns: `ab@nmfn.com`

I can't, however, run this against an xml, as (again), I don't have any sample data of that format from the OP.

Comment: just to confirm, this will take care of both ; separated emails in the column, OR space separated emails? I basically need multi index condition here

Comment: @user8834780 the documentation (I've linked to), explains how `PATINDEX` works; it's important you understand the code that you get from a Q&A website. I can't test the above, I don't have any data to work with from you, so why don't you test it and see? If it doesn't work, reply with details. if it does work, mark the answer as the solution, :)

Comment: This worked in the case of: `ab@nmfn.com;ab@northwesternmutual.com` making it `ab@nmfn.com`, but did not work for: `a.b@chase.com
abcd@chase.com` since that remained

Comment: @user8834780 have updated to demonstrate the code working.

Comment: I know what happened.. the query analyzer shows as if there is a space between the emails, but there isn't when I paste it into excel or the browser..sorry about that. In that case is there a way to exclude anything after the first occurrence of .com?

Comment: @user8834780 if there's no space, then that's going to be a problem. Sounds like you have other characters apart from a single whitespace(`' '`) or a semicolon (`';'`) to cater for.

Comment: @user8834780 if it's a special character (like a line break (`CHAR(10)`)) then you could use a variable to put the splitter values in. For example `DECLARE @Splitter varchar(10) = '%[ ;' + CHAR(10) + ']%'`. Then, instead of the first parameter for `PATINDEX` being `'%[ ;]%'`   use `@Splitter`.

Comment: that's exactly what it was- and worked perfectly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the XML approach.  The only trick is to "Clean" the string first.

This little trick Gordon demonstrated several months ago.  I can't find the original link, but it will reduce multiple spaces and/or semi-colons down to one (expand, reduce, and finally eliminates).  Simply brilliant, only wish I could take credit for it.

**Example**

```
Declare @t table (Id INT, email_address VARCHAR(1000) , email_new VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1,'a.b@wellsfargoadvisors.com', 'a.b@wellsfargoadvisors.com'),
(2,'c.b@RaymondJames.com;;;;   abc@RaymondJames.com', 'abc@RaymondJames.com'      ),
(3,'a.b@boa.com  bbc@boa.com; hh@bankofamerica.com','a.b@boa.com'               )

Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  @t A
 Cross Apply (values (replace(replace(replace(replace(email_address,' ','<>'),';','<>'),'><',''),'<>',';'))
             ) B(CleanString)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(CleanString,';','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Pos1                        Pos2                    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5
1   a.b@wellsfargoadvisors.com  NULL                    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   c.b@RaymondJames.com        abc@RaymondJames.com    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   a.b@boa.com                 bbc@boa.com             hh@bankofamerica.com    NULL    NULL
```