# SQL String_Split

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, split, substring

I have a table which has the following data:

```
ColumnName
============================================
/abc/def/xyz
/abc/def/xyz
/abc/def/xyz
/abc/def/xyz
/abc/xyz
```

I want an output like this

```
Column1     Column2         Column3
abc         def             xyz
abc         def             xyz
abc         def             xyz
abc         def             xyz
abc         xyz             NULL
```

I have tried using SUBSTRING and REPLACE functions but I cannot go past the second "/"

Comment: What are you tries with SUBSTRING so far?

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063415/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-normalize-text-from-column-into-a-table/50064225#50064225

Comment: What version of SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jason A. Long's answer is correct but it is unable to handle if only two '/' are there.
For example:
If one column has "/abc/xyz". The query won't return the value the user wants.

The following query handles the dynamic number of delimiters:

```
SELECT ColName, 
       Len(ColName) - Len(Replace(ColName, '/', '')), 
       CASE 
         WHEN Len(ColName) - Len(Replace(ColName, '/', '')) = 3 THEN 
         Parsename(Replace(ColName, '/', '.'), 3) 
         ELSE Parsename(Replace(ColName, '/', '.'), 2) 
       END, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Len(ColName) - Len(Replace(ColName, '/', '')) = 3 THEN 
         Parsename(Replace(ColName, '/', '.'), 2) 
         ELSE Parsename(Replace(ColName, '/', '.'), 1) 
       END, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Len(ColName) - Len(Replace(ColName, '/', '')) = 3 THEN 
         Parsename(Replace(ColName, '/', '.'), 1) 
       END 
FROM   TableName
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the last value, just use the PARSENAME function.

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('/RockReports/Custom/getConcordManagement', '/', '.'), 1);
```

Comment: Can also be used for the 1st & 2nd value :-)

Comment: This doesn't look at all like what OP wants. They want to parse all values from the string, not just return the last value. Also, this fails at 4 delimited values because parsename is meant for fully qualified server/db/schema/object names, not parsing strings.

Comment: PARSENAME only allows 4 positions and moves from right to left. So, no, it does not fail at 4... It fails at 5. Or... It may be better to say, if the string has more than 3 delimiters, the function will return a NULL value.

Comment: It's a little hacky, but it's a heck of a lot easier than messing with string_split and cross apply.

Comment: It is what it is... It's a function designed to dissect a, 4 part, fully qualified, object name, and not choke if it’s not given all 4 parts. 
In that capacity, it’s brilliant… Unfortunately, we almost never need it in that capacity.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the data remains same, then probably you can try using following code, including instr and substr combined--

```
select columnname, 
       substr(columnname,2,(instr(columnname,'/',1,2)-1)) as col1,  
       substr(columnname,(instr(columnname,'/',1,2)+1),instr(columnname,'/',1,3)-instr(columnname,'/',1,2)-1) as col2,
       substr(columnname,(instr(columnname,'/',1,3)+1),length(columnname)-instr(columnname,'/',1,3)) as col3
  from <table>;
```